# How to find out which files get installed with make?

Tags: git, make

A lot of repositories on Github have an "automatic" installer like the one posted below. I always wonder how to find out which binaries will get installed but I can not figure it out from the script.

This is an example from [libbitcoin-explorer](https://github.com/libbitcoin/libbitcoin-explorer/blob/master/install.sh).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most "installers" (be it a custom one like the one that you link to, or a Makefile that is created from a GNU autotools `configure` script, or a CMake or Meson build specification etc.) allows you to set an installation prefix.  The one you point to, for example, seems to have a `--prefix` option.  The `--prefix` option is also used by GNU autotools `configure` scripts and Meson, while CMake uses `-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`.

Usually, the default installation prefix is `/usr/local`, but setting it to someplace else would allow you to install the software in a clean, previously unpopulated, file hierarchy.

Using this `--prefix` option to install in a non-default location such as `/tmp/testdir`, you would be able to investigate the installation directory to see exactly what is installed (assuming that the script is using the given path as a true installation prefix and does not try to install anything outside of that path; you will have to read the script to find out if that is the case).

Answer (score 1):

You could use `checkinstall` to do create a package to install.

Then use your package manager to install it and afterwards
use your package manager to show you the files, e.g. `dpkg -l package`

From `man checkinstall` (emphasis mine):

> checkinstall is a program that monitors an installation procedure
>   (**such as make install, install.sh**), and creates a standard package
>   for your distribution (currently **deb, rpm and
>   tgz packages are supported**) that you can install through your distribution's
>   package management system (dpkg, rpm or installpkg).

If you create a tgz-package you don't even need to install it: `tar --list thepackage.tgz` will list the contents of the package.

Comment: `checkinstall` seems very interesting! But since I am not using `make install` myself I wonder if it would work in my setup. As I said I use a script `install.sh` which does all the work, including the `make` (and this is recommended by the programmers of the project).

Comment: No matter, `checkinstall` works fine tracking `install.sh`.

Comment: Indeed, `checkinstall ./install.sh --prefix=/... --build-boost ...` works, I am even able to append `| tee log.txt` for logging purpose. But the install script fails on the first attempt to download with `wget`. It only fails with `checkinstall`, it works past this stage without `checkinstall`.