# reliable way to find added/modified files by make install

Tags: package-management, make, lfs

i was about to ask this question yesterday and when i hit the review button, the "similar questions" window has been modified to show me this one: [How to find out which files get installed with make?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/543783/how-to-find-out-which-files-get-installed-with-make)

i thought it was good enough but i'm not satisfied

i'm reading the lfs book and i'm at the chapter that speaks about [package management](https://linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/11.0/chapter08/pkgmgt.html). there's a link to the hints section to get a broader view on the subject and one of these hints says:

> Beside that I also notice that there is currently no 100% reliable
> method to know what files [are] modified during a "make install" (or
> other command).
>
> The fakeroot approach doesn't prevent a package to install files where
> it wants, of course.
>
> [TRIP, a TRIvial Packager for LFS (and other linux systems)](https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/hints/downloads/files/package_management_using_trip.txt)

what i understand:

- it happens that a makefile can fail to use $DESTDIR properly
- the text is from 2006, so it may be outdated (but it happened)

i've always used pre-compiled package-managers and i don't know how often the teams behind had to correct such bugs. i don't understand how parsing the makefile could fail to be "100% reliable"

Comment: I like the Package Users method myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One sample way to get the list of file operations done by `make install` is to execute:

```
make -n install
```

This command will not install/change anything, just will print what actually would be done w/o `-n` key (normal install)

Comment: guess i'm still too hasty if i didn't man, sorry and thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

Use [GNU stow](https://www.gnu.org/software/stow/) or [CheckInstall](http://checkinstall.izto.org)

`stow`:

> GNU Stow is a software installation manager for /usr/local.  Using
> symbolic links, GNU Stow helps you keep the installations separate
> (/usr/local/stow/emacs vs. /usr/local/stow/perl, for example) while
> maintaining the illusion that they are all under /usr/local.

and `CheckInstall`:

> CheckInstall keeps track of all the files created or
> modified by your installation script ("make install"
> "make install_modules", "setup", etc), builds a
> standard binary package and installs it in your
> system giving you the ability to uninstall it with your
> distribution's standard package management utilities.

Comment: stow is a cool solution thanks!